# TDD with Linq Any() and All()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, tdd

I'm writing a method that does a Linq query and I'm trying to do that using TDD.

However, my query now has a `Any()`, but sometimes I remove or change things in my code after writing my tests to see if my tests cover everything that should be covered.

Then I started to change `Any()` for `All()` just for fun, and my test still passed.

I was wondering if I had to check all the different cases like so I get all `All()` and `Any()` combinations:

1. Given that my list contains zero elements (`All()` would return `true`, but `Any()` would return `false`)
2. Given that my list contains some elements and only one satisfies the predicate
3. Given that my list contains some elements and all of them satisfy the predicate

I've read in several books of TDD that people often "fake" the code, just so the test fails. But in this case I have to write more code than necessary to fake it.

Comment: What are you testing? If you change Any to All without other modifications it means you're changing the result of your method.

Comment: I'm not trying to change the result, but to check if my test is really testing something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is simple: you clearly don't have enough tests to cover all the possibilities. Without knowing your domain, or exactly what you're testing, you probably needs tests for

- empty
- not empty, all satisfy
- not empty, some satisfy
- not empty, none satisfy